# Handle multiple pulls in Local Git Repo

Tags: ruby, git, synchronization, sinatra

I have Sinatra service that updates a local git repo by executing `git pull` when it is hit. Since it is a write, I want only one `git pull` to happen at a time. How do I effectively detect if a `pull` is already happening ? Currently am just checking if `index.lock` file exists in `.git` directory.

```
if @file_obj.exists? "#{@data_dir}/.git/index.lock"
    @log.info('********* LOCKED **********')
else
  MUTEX.synchronize do
    @log.info('********* Inside Sync **********')
    @executor.run(git_pull_command, in: @data_dir)
  end
end
```

Comment: Put a mutex on `@executor.run`. But the better strategy would be to _calnel_ current pull on subsequent request and restart it, since you probably want to end up with an up-to-date version. Also, since you handle everything, you might want to create your own lock file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure git handles its own locking. Why not just handle the locking error gracefully?

Answer (score 0):

`index.lock` is probably the only file that you need to worry about.  Since you're using a mutex to synchronize your operations, this code should be fine.

Git only really creates the `index.lock` file when it needs to have sole control over the `index` for a while (and to prevent other Git processes from clobbering stuff).  This would only happen while the pull is completing.